# Why is the training time of each epoch different heavily?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model in Keras. I find that the time of each epoch is nearly same in the  fist 10 epochs, about 140s every epoch. But in the successive epochs,the training time increases to about 500s every epoch.

So, what‘s the problem?

```
184s - loss: 0.2587 - fscore_cloud: 0.8348 - val_loss: 0.1987 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8781
Epoch 2/2000
163s - loss: 0.1899 - fscore_cloud: 0.8868 - val_loss: 0.1927 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8877
Epoch 3/2000
144s - loss: 0.1821 - fscore_cloud: 0.8915 - val_loss: 0.1885 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8910
Epoch 4/2000
143s - loss: 0.1794 - fscore_cloud: 0.8931 - val_loss: 0.1856 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8930
Epoch 5/2000
142s - loss: 0.1784 - fscore_cloud: 0.8937 - val_loss: 0.1846 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8935
Epoch 6/2000
142s - loss: 0.1774 - fscore_cloud: 0.8939 - val_loss: 0.1835 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8940
Epoch 7/2000
144s - loss: 0.1766 - fscore_cloud: 0.8942 - val_loss: 0.1827 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8944
Epoch 8/2000
141s - loss: 0.1759 - fscore_cloud: 0.8944 - val_loss: 0.1820 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8947
Epoch 9/2000
139s - loss: 0.1754 - fscore_cloud: 0.8946 - val_loss: 0.1813 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8950
Epoch 10/2000
184s - loss: 0.1749 - fscore_cloud: 0.8947 - val_loss: 0.1806 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8952
Epoch 11/2000
544s - loss: 0.1743 - fscore_cloud: 0.8948 - val_loss: 0.1800 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8954
Epoch 12/2000
545s - loss: 0.1738 - fscore_cloud: 0.8950 - val_loss: 0.1796 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8955
Epoch 13/2000
553s - loss: 0.1731 - fscore_cloud: 0.8952 - val_loss: 0.1791 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8957
Epoch 14/2000
214s - loss: 0.1723 - fscore_cloud: 0.8955 - val_loss: 0.1776 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8961
Epoch 15/2000
145s - loss: 0.1706 - fscore_cloud: 0.8965 - val_loss: 0.1768 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8964
Epoch 16/2000
146s - loss: 0.1683 - fscore_cloud: 0.8975 - val_loss: 0.1743 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8980
Epoch 17/2000
140s - loss: 0.1658 - fscore_cloud: 0.8983 - val_loss: 0.1734 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8986
Epoch 18/2000
142s - loss: 0.1640 - fscore_cloud: 0.8987 - val_loss: 0.1719 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.8990
Epoch 19/2000
137s - loss: 0.1621 - fscore_cloud: 0.8996 - val_loss: 0.1699 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9001
Epoch 20/2000
277s - loss: 0.1601 - fscore_cloud: 0.9007 - val_loss: 0.1678 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9015
Epoch 21/2000
310s - loss: 0.1579 - fscore_cloud: 0.9018 - val_loss: 0.1655 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9028
Epoch 22/2000
345s - loss: 0.1558 - fscore_cloud: 0.9031 - val_loss: 0.1635 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9042
Epoch 23/2000
587s - loss: 0.1538 - fscore_cloud: 0.9044 - val_loss: 0.1621 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9054
Epoch 24/2000
525s - loss: 0.1519 - fscore_cloud: 0.9056 - val_loss: 0.1610 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9061
Epoch 25/2000
579s - loss: 0.1500 - fscore_cloud: 0.9068 - val_loss: 0.1597 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9069
Epoch 26/2000
557s - loss: 0.1485 - fscore_cloud: 0.9075 - val_loss: 0.1575 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9078
Epoch 27/2000
530s - loss: 0.1469 - fscore_cloud: 0.9084 - val_loss: 0.1561 - val_fscore_cloud: 0.9083
Epoch 28/2000
```

Comment: To answer your question we need to know what you actually do. Batch size? Data?

Comment: ... other processes possibly taking resources from your CPU/GPU?

Comment: Do you use `Callbacks`?

Comment: I found this problem is relative the GPU, some other program may allocate the GPU resource.So, the process time of each epoch different a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem. Even when we just run `torch.cuda.FloatTensor(a,b).normal_()` every epoch, the latter epochs will take longer than previous epochs. I guess that this phenomenon is caused by memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it would be preferable to post is as a comment rather.